# Where does user stylesheet in Chrome DevTools come from?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, userstyles

This issue is under Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m.

[image: Styles side panel in Chrome DevTools displaying a user stylesheet]

So I have the above. You can see that the element (it's some text) has a `color` set (via a .css file) - however, the *user stylesheet* is setting the background to the same colour. This code:

```
background: rgb(255, 145, 0)
```

It cannot be disabled and I cannot find it anywhere in my code. Where might this be being picked up from? It's not in my .css or within my .php script. Where does the *user stylesheet* come from if not within a .css file?

Comment: you might find interest [reading this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/userstylesheets/a/aa010906.htm)?

Comment: @jbutler483 - I'm aware of what a User Style Sheet is - what I am asking is where is the user style sheet that Firebug refers to?

Comment: It *could possibly* be within a style sheet of your browser's app data folder (To ensure it's not, could you try opening the same styling in another browser? )

Comment: Yup, it's Chrome add-on that's causing it - how annoying!

Comment: You're using Chrome and the screenshot shows the Chrome DevTools. So how is this related to Firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Chrome plug-in [Hootsuite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hootsuite/kneloppijbcidgidihgdjnooihjcdbij) was causing the issue. Once removed, all OK.

Comment: Which plug-in was it that you removed?

Comment: Hootsuite was removed.